# How to prevent default click behavior of a routerlink in angular app?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-routing

Even though this is not angular specific in theory it needs to be solved in ng app and none of the examples work. I've seen all the answers in SO but none of those solutions seem to work in real life Angular7 app. For example none of the following work :

```
<!-- option 1 -->
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/properties", sessionId]'
 (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">Properties
</a>
<!-- option 2 -->
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/properties", sessionId]'
 (click)="$event.stopPropagation();false">Properties
</a>
<!-- option 3 -->
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/properties", sessionId]'
 (click)="$event.preventDefault()">Properties
</a>
<!-- option 4 -->
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/properties", sessionId]'
 (click)="$event.preventDefault();false">Properties
</a>
```

Creating a method for handler in component.ts and calling either function with or without returning false does not work either.

In addition, I don't want to disable link because it needs to be draggable / openable in other browser tab/window.

EDIT: Here is https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21457 and I can make it to work by adding an element inside anchor and have the click for the inside element like this:

```
(click)="$event.stopPropagation();$event.preventDefault()"
```

My real world example has mat-icon inside anchor so I use that but in link above a span inside is suggested.

Comment: I personally have used return false and it works like a charm. Can you create a plunkr?

Comment: thanks for comment! (click)="return false" throws syntaxError in compiler.js TemplateParser. I have tried that also.

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a> .Use this.

Comment: @AyatullahRahmani: why would that work?

Comment: What you are probably looking for is the ```CanDeactivate``` guard. https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate

Answer (score 18):

The reason routerLink does not respect `preventDefault` is described [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21457).

The solution is to create inner element for anchor if there already isn't one (like icon). In the link above a span is created inside but I have icons inside anchors which I omitted from the question for clarity:

```
  <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/map", sessionId]'>
    <mat-icon class="tab-nav-item-icon" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();$event.preventDefault()">map</mat-icon>
  </a>
```